# Lost on installing Ubuntu on my laptop with an ATI graphics card

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, ati, console

I just bought a new laptop and I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it.
The laptop has an ATI graphic card though which led to the problem of it simply black-screening and not booting. There already is a proposed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782), but I don't seem to understand where the code changes should be made. When I try to enter `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` into the Grub console which you can access through pressing "c" while in Grub, it says that the command is unknown. So where should I enter the code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run `sudo` and `nano` before your system has even booted (grub is just the bootloader). Hit CTRL+ALT+F1 when reaching the log-in screen to go directly to a terminal instead of GUI.

You can then make said commands.

Comment: I don't even get that far, sadly. I just get a black screen and can't do anything about that, I guess I'll just try reinstalling....

Comment: Can you plug and boot from a liveUSB or liveCD? You should be able to open a terminal from that, and then modify the file on your disk .